# how could i display the dynamic value in a html table

Tags: java, html, spring

i have a retrieve data from list & i want to place them in a exact  how could i do this please give a helpful suggestion to do it.

java class for creating list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.demo.Rules;

public class CompArray {
public ArrayList<Rules> a1= new ArrayList<Rules>();

public CompArray (){
    Rules rul = new Rules();
    rul.setId("1001");
    rul.setDetails("khagfkj");
    rul.setParameter("lsrkjglkrs");
    rul.setValue("lskdjfk");
a1.add(rul);
```

}

public ArrayList getRules(){

return a1;

}

}

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/compplan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listRules1(ModelMap model) {
    CompArray obj1 = new CompArray();
    model.addAttribute("listRule1", obj1);
    return "hello";
}
```

Html

```
<c:if test="${!empty listRule1}">
                <table  border ="2">
                    <tr>
                        <th align="center"><b>ID</b></th>
                        <th align="center"><b>Details </b></th>
                        <th align="center"><b>Parameter </b></th>
                        <th align="center"><b>Value</b></th>
                    </tr>

 <c:forEach items="${listRule1}" var="obj1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${obj1.id}</td>
                            <td>${obj1.details}</td>
                            <td>${obj1.parameter}</td>
                            <td>${obj1.value}</td>

                        </tr>                           
                    </c:forEach>

                </table></c:if>
```

I am doing in this way but its not display the value in a table, please help me.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `<c:if test="${!empty listRule1}">` to `<c:if test="${not empty listRule1}">` and give it a try

Comment: sir could you tell me in little bit details..??

Comment: Basically you can't use the `!` operator in jstl, instead you need to use the word `not`